# Sphere half-submerged on a dielectric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, dielectric

This is a classic problem in electrostatics with a twist, so I thought it could be useful for others here. I did have a problem with the integration at the end, but on general I think the idea can help others.

The idea is that a conductor, chargeless sphere of radius R is floating half-submerged on a liquid with dielectric constant (the upper half is in air, with dielectric constant equal 1). Now a differential of charge $\delta Q$ is added to the surface and the sphere moves, and we want to find how much it displaces.

**Question**

Find the displacement of the sphere in terms of the differential charge

**My attempt at a solution**

While I don't know if it's really useful, if we apply mechanical equilibrium before adding the charge, it's straightforward to find that $\rho_s=\rho_l$,  where $\rho_s$ and $\rho_l$ are the volumetric densities of the sphere and the liquid, respectively.

After adding the charge, we can suppose that the sphere moves upwards (the direction doesn't matter, since at the end the sign will determine the correct one). Assuming the charge distributes uniformily over the surface, we can apply Gauss Law to find that:

$$\int_{air} \vec{D}\cdot d\vec{A}+\int_{liquid}\vec{D}\cdot d\vec{A}=\delta Q$$

Letting $\delta y$ be the vertical distance that the sphere moves up (the area is a small ring of perimeter $2\pi R$ and height $\delta y$), and since the electric field (and thus the displacement) of a submerged sphere is radial:

$$D_{air}(2\pi R^2+2\pi \delta y)+D_{liquid}(2\pi R^2-2\pi \delta y)=\delta Q$$

[image: Figure 1: Sphere after adding charge]

Assuming an isotropic, homogenous, linear dielectric, we can apply the constitutive relationship $\vec{D}=\epsilon \vec{E}$ to find that:

$$\vec{E}=\frac{1}{2\pi a}\frac{\delta Q}{(a+\delta y)+\epsilon(a-\delta y)}$$

And thus:

$$\vec{D_{air}}=\frac{1}{2\pi a}\frac{\delta Q}{(a+\delta y)+\epsilon(a-\delta y)}$$

$$\vec{D_{liquid}}=\frac{\epsilon}{2\pi a}\frac{\delta Q}{(a+\delta y)+\epsilon(a-\delta y)}$$

Now, for these kinds of materials, the energy of the fields is:

$$U_E=\int d^3 r \vec{E}\cdot\vec{D}$$

Substituting:

$$U_E=\frac{(\delta Q)^2}{4\pi^2 a^2}\left ( \int_{air} \frac{d^3r}{((a+\delta y)+\epsilon(a-\delta y))^2} + \epsilon\int_{liquid} \frac{d^3r}{((a+\delta y)+\epsilon(a-\delta y))^2} \right )$$

To first order, we can simplify the denominator since $\delta y$ is small:

$$((a+\delta y)+\epsilon(a-\delta y))^2=a^2(1+3\epsilon)+2a\delta y(1-\epsilon^2)$$

Therefore:

$$U_E=\frac{(\delta Q)^2}{4\pi^2 a^2}\left ( \int_{air} \frac{d^3r}{a^2(1+3\epsilon)+2a\delta y(1-\epsilon^2)} + \epsilon\int_{liquid} \frac{d^3r}{a^2(1+3\epsilon)+2a\delta y(1-\epsilon^2)} \right )$$

Now, if we could just express $\delta y$ as a function of spherical coordinates we could perform the integral, so I got stuck here.

However, assuming we can do the above integral, we can easily find the force as:

$$F_E=-\left ( \frac{\partial U_E}{\partial R} \right )_{\delta Q}$$

And perform a new mechanical equilibrium equation:

$$\rho_l V_{submerged} g - \rho_s V_{total} g +F_E=0$$

And theoretically find the submerged volume to find the percentage that the sphere moved after adding the charge (don't forget we calculated $\rho_s=\rho_l/2$)

If I'm allowed to ask: is my intuition about finding the displacement correct? Or how can I find it if I consider a virtual displacement aroound the equilibrium position instead?

I have received the suggestion to consider the equilibrium state and then apply a first order perturbation in $\delta Q$, which should be easier but I can't find a way to do it this way.

Comment: cant we use electrostatic pressure instead of this complex inegration?

Comment: How would that be? I've never used electrostatic pressure to solve problems.

Comment: like see its just an idea imagine that when the charge is given it would distribute on the surfaces as τ₁ and τ₂ and this would lead to an excess pressure downwards and force due to this will be pressure times projected area. the only problem i  encountered is that i need two equations between τ₁ and τ₂ one is from charge conservation other i think would follow from gauss law but haven't tried yet

Comment: Yeah, I checked the topic on Zangwill and you could theoretically calculate the pressures from the electric field. However, as you stated you need to find the two equations for the charges on each side. Maybe one can calculate the surface charges (which follow straight from the field $\vec{D}$), but I don't see how you can relate it to the virtual displacement of the problem.

Comment: They also told me one could start from the equilibrium position and then consider a virtual displacement, I'll ask for a bounty in a couple of hours to study this case.

Comment: @AdityaGarg I asked the course assistant about the electrostatic pressure, and the problem with using it is that it will give the net force from within inside the sphere, so at the end the result won't be useful to calculate the displacement. Instead, they suggested to either find the energy, or to consider the equilibrium case (half-submerged) and then apply a small perturbation (virtual displacement) to understand how the sphere will move. If we apply then the conditions of equilibirum (i.e. the derivative of the perturbation is an extremal, then we could find the answer.

Comment: I don't think that we can assume that the charge distribution is uniform. Won't the dipoles in the liquid attract the charge in the conductor leading to an excess charge in the bottom half?